# How do you extract an image from a pdf file using C#

Tags: c#, image, pdf, bitmap

How can I get the image from a .pdf file into a System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for the task.

Here is a sample that shows how to create `System.Drawing.Bitmap` from an image in a PDF file:

```
static void GetImagesFromPdfAsBitmaps()
{
    string pathToPdf = "";
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pathToPdf))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdf.Images[i].Save(ms);

                // don't forget to rewind stream
                ms.Position = 0;

                System.Drawing.Image bitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
                // ... use the bitmap and then dispose it
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The library can also save images to files. The library doesn't resample images (i.e. you'll get exactly the same image as in PDF)

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle, vendor of the library.

Comment: Is this library still free for non-commercial use? I don't see mention of it on the web site.

Comment: @paulwhit Unfortunately, it's no longer so. Sorry, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For anything having to do with PDFs in .NET I recommend [iText#](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch01.html)

It looks like it is [possible](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=530736) to extract images but I have not had a chance to test this.

Hope this helps and good luck :)

Comment: My experience with both iText# and PdfSharp is that they're better at writing pdf files than reading them.

Comment: @Joel - Wish I could +1 a comment. ;)